# drawing a rectangle for user-defined dimensions using for lops, using extended ASCII characters

Tags: c

I did some part of it but can't seem to get the whole rectangle. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
printf("Enter the length and width of the rectangle : ");
scanf("%d%d",&length,&width);


printf("\n%c", 218);
for(i=1;i<=length;i++)
{
        printf("%c",196);

}

printf("%c",191);


 for(j=1;j<=width;j++)
 {
     printf("\n");
     printf("%c",179);
 }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c", 192);

     for(i=1;i<=length;i++)
{
        printf("%c",196);

}

printf("%c", 217);

return 0;
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63lDC.png)

Comment: You only print the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your middle loop, you only print a single vertical bar before going to the next line.

You need to print the bar once, then add another loop to print the spaces, then print one more bar:

```
  for(j=1;j<=width;j++)
  {
     printf("\n");
     printf("%c",179);
     for (i=1;i<=length;i++) {
       printf(" ");
     }
     printf("%c",179);
  }
```

Comment: `for (i=1;i<=length;i++)` shouldn't that be `for (i=1;i<=length-2;i++)`? Since you need `length-2` spaces?

Comment: @Osiris The code printing the top and bottom bars is using the same logic.  It seem the "size" is the internal size, not the external size.

Comment: Yes i missed the `printf`s before and after the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbush, I finally got it

Comment: @Nagarjunrao Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are only printing the first column and not the second one.
An approach would be to loop over the whole rectangle and check if you are at an edge or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int length, width, i, j;

    printf("Enter the length and width of the rectangle : ");
    scanf("%d%d",&length, &width);

    for(i=0;i<width;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<length;j++)
        {
            if( j==0 || j==length-1 || i==0 || i==width-1 )
            {
                printf("%c", '*');
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int length, width,i,j;
   printf("Enter the length and width of the rectangle : ");
   scanf("%d%d",&length,&width);


printf("\n%c", 218);
for(i=1;i<=length;i++)
{
    printf("%c",196);

 }

   printf("%c",191);


    for(j=1;j<=width;j++)
 {
 printf("\n");
 printf("%c",179);
 for (i=1;i<=length;i++) {
   printf(" ");
 }
  printf("%c",179);
  }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c", 192);

  for(i=1;i<=length;i++)
   { 
    printf("%c",196);

    }

 printf("%c", 217);

  return 0;
 }
```